# Does mdbg support conditional breakpoints?

Tags: c#, .net, windbg, mdbg

I am debugging a "Hello World" program written in C# using `mdgb`, but it seems `gdb`-style conditional breakpoints failed to set in `mdbg`, e.g.

```
  [p#:0, t#:0] mdbg> when 1 sum>100
  Error: Invalid command syntax
```

[image: TODO: fixme image]

This is when related syntax, but i still don't know how to setup conditional breakpoint in mdbg, althoug I read [mdbg documenation [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861(v=vs.110).aspx)

[image: TODO: fixme image]

So what is `cond 1 sum>100` in mdbg?

How do I set a breakpoint conditionally?

[image]

**Edit 1**
@ThomasWeller  your when clause is correct in syntax, but it seems it's not a conditional breakpoint, since `g` hit the breakpoint again, and the when clause not works, if it works, g should break when sum is larger than 100, but in fact `g` breaks when sum is 1, far smaller than 100 :(
[image]

**Edit 2**
`when BreakpointHit 1 do echo sum>100` not works
[image]

Comment: I think the when command is used like `when AssemblyLoaded do echo sum>100`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller read edit 1, your method not works.

Comment: Well, `when BreakpointHit 1 do echo sum>100`

Comment: @ThomasWeller not works, see edit 2

Answer (score 3):

Conditional Breakpoints aren't supported. If you were really really serious about getting conditional breakpoints in MDbg you could download the source and add the feature:
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2282

Alternatively you could grab a free version of Visual Studio which supports conditional breakpoints.

Comment: how do you know mdbg does not support conditional breakpoint?

Comment: I work for Microsoft on the .Net Framework team. Among other responsibilities I would consider myself the owner of the MDbg source code ; )

Comment: lol, mdbg is very nice tool, better with conditional breakpoint enabled:)

Comment: do you use cdb as c++ debug, i have one question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011043/how-to-set-breakpoint-and-show-source-code-when-using-cdb-to-debug-c-programs